# SQL Query to get empty categories too

Tags: sql, join, group-by

In my `categories` table I have: `cat_id`, `cat_name`, `cat_slug`. 
In the table `items` I have: `item_title,` `item_id`, `item_category`.

```
`item_category` = `cat_id`
```

I'm using the following SQL to get "all" categories and how many items they have:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`item_id`) 
FROM `menu_categories` 
    JOIN `menu_items` ON `item_category` = `cat_id` 
GROUP BY `item_category`
```

But it doesn't show empty `categories`, i.e. `categories` without items.

Comment: Replace `join` with `left join`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`item_id`) 
FROM `menu_categories`
  LEFT JOIN `menu_items` ON `item_category` = `cat_id`
GROUP BY `item_category`
```

Have a look at [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, also had to change `GROUP BY` to *cat_id*. =)

Answer (score 3):

Use a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT *, COUNT(`item_id`) 
FROM `menu_categories` 
    LEFT JOIN `menu_items` 
        ON `item_category` = `cat_id` 
GROUP BY `item_category`
```