# Including 0 On Count when Filtering on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Listed below is my code. It returns the count of each category that a person has been in for a movie. It returns the result but I would like it to list every category including the ones with 0 counts. I tried every combination of LEFT JOIN, OUTER JOIN, etc and it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(f.title) FROM category c
LEFT JOIN film_category fc ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
INNER JOIN film f ON fc.film_id = f.film_id
INNER JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
INNER JOIN actor a ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
WHERE a.first_name = 'Jack' AND a.last_name = 'Daniel'
GROUP BY c.name ASC;
```

Comment: Perhaps `...sum(if(name is null, 1, 1))...` instead of count may work.

Comment: I know your schema setup and query seem very complicated, but this is basically the same problem anyone who wants to select categories with 0 items in it would face in SQL in a typical ER model.   So the answer is out there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177444/sql-query-to-get-empty-categories-too   I reckon you need to change your first INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, but this is a lot to setup and test for me.

Comment: Change all `inner joins` to `left joins` and move your `where` criteria to the joins...

Answer (score 1):

Try this. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46ecb/1/0)

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(f.title) FROM category c
LEFT JOIN film_category fc ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
LEFT JOIN film f ON fc.film_id = f.film_id
LEFT JOIN film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
LEFT JOIN actor a ON fa.actor_id = a.actor_id and a.first_name = 'Jack' AND a.last_name = 'Daniel'
WHERE 1=1 
GROUP BY c.name ASC;
```

Comment: It was the "WHERE" clause that was killing Solomon--that automatically filtered out "non-matching" rows.   By moving the name selector to the join criteria, the database was able to return all category rows, matching or not.    Well done!

Comment: Unless film.title is declared `NOT NULL`, you should instead `COUNT(f.film_id)` to avoid a film with a null title not being counted.

Comment: Hi @Solomon if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score -1):

Union the inverse criteria of your query, eg

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(f.ti....
...

UNION 

SELECT c.name, 0
FROM category c
...
WHERE NOT(a.first_name = 'Jack' AND a.last_name = 'Daniel')
...
```